# Fingerprint of RSA public key

Tags: ssl, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to get a fingerprint from a public key created as below:

```
openssl genrsa -out test.pem -aes128 -passout pass:testphrase 2048
openssl rsa -pubout -in test.pem -out test_public.pem -passin pass:testphrase
```

I'm uploading the public key to my cloud provider which confirms the fingerprint to be `70:d6:cb:9c:c7:95:ad:6f:49:84:4f:d1:fb:71:a8:53` and I can get the fingerprint from the private key using this command

```
openssl rsa -in test.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c

(stdin)= 70:d6:cb:9c:c7:95:ad:6f:49:84:4f:d1:fb:71:a8:53
```

I've tried

```
openssl rsa -pubin test_public.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c
```

But this gives me `d4:1d:8c:d9:8f:00:b2:04:e9:80:09:98:ec:f8:42:7e`.
I'd like to get the fingerprint directly from the public key, I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: You can save and check the DER formatted output of the last two openssl commands and view their structure using https://lapo.it/asn1js This might be helpful to understand how they differ and thus have a different fingerprint.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Both statements return the same hash on my machine. Are you sure that you determine the hashes of related keys? By the way, the last OpenSSL statement is missing a `-in` before `test_public.pem`. But this is probably just a copy/paste error, because this produces an error message and not a wrong hash.

Comment: I'd somehow missed the `rsa: Use -help for summary.` part of `rsa: Use -help for summary.
(stdin)= d4:1d:8c:d9:8f:00:b2:04:e9:80:09:98:ec:f8:42:7e
`

Comment: @Robert: you don't need a website; `openssl asn1parse [-inform der]` is as good. But you don't even need to parse; the real problem here, as noted, is that the second command has a syntax error and doesn't produce _any_ output data (only an error message, on stderr) and you could see that difference with `ls -l` or `cmp` -- or `dir` or `fc /b`.

Comment: @Topaco: actually `rsa` produces an error message and _no_ output, and `md5 -c` with no _input_ produces the hash of no data aka empty or null which is the `d41d...` value.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - That was simply a typo by the OP. If `-in` is added, the statement works. If `-in` is omitted, an error message is displayed (_unknown option..._), and yes, the hash value for empty data (I had missed the latter).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Did not know that openssl also can decode asn.1, unfortunately the output is not very helpful as it does not show any structure, so it is IMHO useless without the matching RFC and a lot of knowledge. This output may be helpful for experts, but not for regular users. The website I have linked to does parsing in JS on client side, should be possible to use it offline. And it's output is easy to read so that you can get an overview what is inside a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so thanks to @Topaco I now know that the commands

```
openssl rsa -in test.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c
```

and

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in test_public.pem -outform DER | openssl md5 -c
```

Give the same hash, I'd missed the `-in` flag before `test_public.pem`.